# How to send video across WiFiDirect between tablets with Xamarin.Forms on UWP

Tags: c#, video, xamarin.forms, uwp, wifi-direct

I am writing a C# UWP app which needs to communicate via WifiDirect (with Xamarin.Forms, but that's not really relevant at the moment). I have the WiFiDirect parts working and other services are up and running.  I now need to send video of the facial movements of one tablet (Surface Pro 4) user to another. I can access both cameras on the tablets and I could just send data frame by frame via a socket, but this seems sub-optimal.  Is there a better way of going about this?

Comment: Using TCP and UDP sockets and send data should be a better way. The official code sample also uses sockets to send data. https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WiFiDirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question because I figured out the way; it is not obvious but Microsoft actually provide a sample that helps with this; https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SimpleCommunication/cs

Comment: In fact WebRTC is a better way still; the PeerCC sample work very well; https://github.com/microsoft/WebRTC-universal-samples